# How to prototype function in diferent context

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have function where i pass another 2 functions as parameters, something like:

doSomething(func1,func2)

What i need is to prototype the func1 in other context when the function is being exported.

For example i have 2 diferent files:

in the first one i export a function that receives 2 parameters functions:

```
module.exports = (func1, func2) => {

}
```

in the second i pass the parameters as i said before like doSomething(func1,func2)

how can i inside the module.exports prototype the toString in the way i can have a output like this of the function1:

**/* func1() */ func2()**

i tried this way:

```
module.exports = (func1, func2) => {

    func1.prototype.toString = function () {
        const comment = `/* ${(_.toString(func1))} */ \n`;
        return comment;
    };
};
```

the result was the func1 without the /* */ any help with this?

Comment: `the result was` how did you get that result?

Comment: Do you want to print function 1 code by overriding toString method?

Comment: i want to print function 2 inside function 1 by prototyping function 1

Comment: I don't think by "*prototype*" you mean what the term "prototype" usually refers to in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define `func1.toString` instead of `func1.prototype.toString`. The former will be used for `func1.toString()`. The latter will be used for *instances* of `func1`, e.g. `(new func1()).toString()`.

Object (including functions) are passed by reference between files/modules. It doesn't matter where you do this.

```
> Foo.prototype.toString = function () { return 'proto-tostring' }
> Foo.toString = function () { return 'ctor-tostring' }
> Foo.toString()
'ctor-tostring'
> (new Foo()).toString()
'proto-tostring'
```